# Getting error while connecting to sql server

Tags: java, sql-server, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone help me on,
I am trying to connect the sql server and do database testing using selenium webdriver the code is:

```
try {
    String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource";
    /*String connection = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customer";*/
    String connection = "jdbc:sqlserver://Leverage-Laptop\\SQLEXPRESS2008R2:1433;integratedSecurity=True;databaseName=TestDataBase;";
    //String userName = "sa";
    //String password = "leverage";
    Class.forName(driver);
    //con = DriverManager.getConnection(connection);

    con = DriverManager.getConnection(connection);
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    return stmt;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am getting a exception as below:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "TestDataBase" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:dc4cee5f-6cb7-4339-8fa8-655d13d525bd

I have disabled Firewall as well as i have copied the sqljdbc_auth dll in jre lib and bin directory.

Comment: Can you connect to this database from your machine using a client tool, like SSMS?  Also, are you certain that this database exists at that location?

Comment: Any errors in the SQL Server's logs? I *assume* that the Login also has a linked User on the database `TestDataBase`?

Comment: Does the SQL Server allow SQL authentication, or only Windows authentication?

Comment: Allows both @SurfMan

Comment: [See this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1423758-391-1.aspx?Update=1&Update=1) It will help

Comment: You are opening two connections. Is it a copy&paste error?

Comment: it was copy&paste error ;) @Andreaジーティーオー

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i am using Mssql in the tool SSMS and s i am able to connect

Comment: Did you added your windows account to the instance SQLEXPRESS2008R2? 
In connection string you are using "integratedSecurity=True". That's meanm that application will try to connecto to server by user wich is owner of the application's process. if you run application by your windwos account then this account must be added on sqlserver as windows login.

Comment: ya its done @AlexanderShapkin

Comment: still i am facing the issue,any other way to do it?...I am trying with many other ways from browsing

Comment: Next you should check what database user have link with sql server login. Every database user must binded to some sql server login.

Comment: Can you show as the properties of the database user which was assigned to the your sql login? 
Can you show the result of this query:
USE [YOUR_DB_NAME]
GO

SELECT 
 dp.name,
 dp.principal_id,
 dp.type,
 dp.default_schema_name,
 dp.sid,
 dp.authentication_type_desc,
 l.name,
 l.type_desc,
 l.default_database_name
FROM sys.database_principals dp 
LEFT JOIN sys.sql_logins l ON l.sid = dp.sid

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got the solution,

1.open window type ODBC configuration 
        2. System DSN 
        3. Add 
        4. SQL server Native Client 11.0 
        5. Finish 
        6. select server 
        7. After creating click on configure 
        8. Next type password and click finish 
        9.click on TestDataSource. check whether DB is connected or not. If its connected then its working fine.Then  run from eclipce IDE.

Comment: You are asking about how to connect to the database by IntegratedSecurity, but your answer using sql login, not your windows account...

Comment: I have no where mentioned that i want solution for either windows or sql authentication,i was trying to get atleast 1 either sql or windows i have got solution for sql authentication.!!

Comment: In your first example code you can see commented sql login and password. Also there is using integratedSecurity=True. Thats mean, you want to connect by Windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use double slash symbols before instance name. Try another syntax.

```
String connection = "jdbc:sqlserver://Leverage-Laptop:1433;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS2008R2;databaseName=TestDataBase;integratedSecurity=True;";
```

More examples: [MSDN arcticle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms378428%28v=sql.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)